# How to pass form values to route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm having trouble passing a value from a form to a route.

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> 'ReportController@index']) !!}

<div class="radio">
     <label><input type="radio" name="report_option" class="report_option" value="call_details">Call Details</label>
</div>
```

`Route::post('reports/{report}', 'ReportController@index');`

Comment: What does your controller look like? What have you tried to get the value?

Answer (score 0):

The action value can be an array to which you can pass the parameter so try this instead:

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> ['ReportController@index', $report]]) !!}
```

Keep in mind that in the view you should have the `$report`.

Comment: How would $report get set to the selected input?

Answer (score 0):

POST request data are not encoded in url its  within the message body of the HTTP request.

```
Route::post('reports', 'ReportController@index');
```

and in your controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
   return $request->report_option;

}
```

Comment: I originally had that and it works but Im looking to have the url look like /reports/report_name.

Comment: then you need to pass the {report} <form action="{{ action('ReportController@index', ['id' => $report->id]) }} >

Comment: @Thomas Grauer for your case  here ['action' => ['ReportController@index', $report->id]

Comment: No matter how I try to pass that in, I get Undefined variable: report

Comment: maybe try making it {id}

Comment: Did you try to pass like this <form action="{{ action('ReportController@index', ['id' => $report->id]) }} > and get in Controller using like parameter ? public function index($id)

Answer (score 0):

Change your route

```
 Route::post('reports/{id}', 'ReportController@index')->name('viewreport');
```

In your controller

```
public function index(Request $request,$id)
{
  // $id is the route value and $request contain other form values passed in the body of the request
}
```

In your view

```
 <form action="{{route('viewreport',['id'=>$report->id])}}" method="post">
```